# Show that if $X:[0,T]\to\mathbb R$ is continuous, then $\inf\left\{t\in\overline I:|X(t)|\geε\right\}\le t$ iff $|X(s)|\geε$ for some $s\in[0,t]$

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, supremum-and-infimum

Let

- $T>0$
- $I:=(0,T]$
- $X:\overline I\to\mathbb R$ be continuous with $X(0)=0$
- $\varepsilon>0$
- $\tau:=\inf\left\{t\in\overline I:|X(t)|\ge\varepsilon\right\}$
- $t\in\overline I$

> How can we show that $\tau\le t$ if and only if $|X(s)|\ge\varepsilon$ for some $s\in[0,t]$?

Clearly, the "if" part is trivial. However, I don't know how we need to argue in the "only if" part. For example, why isn't it possible that $\tau=t$, $|X(s)|<\varepsilon$ for all $s\in[0,t]$ and $|X(s)|\ge\varepsilon$ for all $s\in(t,T]$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It suffices to show that $|X(\tau)| = \epsilon$.

Observe that $\tau \in I$.  Suppose $|X(\tau)|<\epsilon$.  Take $\eta = \frac12(\epsilon - X(\tau))$.  The continuity of $X$ gives a $\delta$-neighbourhood of $\tau$ so that $X(t') \in (X(\tau)-\eta, X(\tau)+\eta) \subseteq (X(\tau)-\eta, \epsilon)$ for all $t' \in (\tau-\delta, \tau+\delta)$.  This contradicts the definition of $\tau$ as a *greatest* lower bound of $\{|X| \ge \epsilon\}$ (because any $t' \in (\tau, \tau + \delta)$ is a *greater* lower bound for $\{|X| \ge \epsilon\}$).

[image]

For this question, we're done with $|X(\tau)| \ge \epsilon$.  (It's given that $\tau \le t$, so $s = \tau$ satisfies the question.)  The rest is left for exercise.

Remarks: In [probability-theory](/questions/tagged/probability-theory), $\tau$ is called the *hitting time* of the event $\{|X| \ge \epsilon\}$, where $\Omega = [0,T]$ equipped with the usual Borel $\sigma$-algebra.  Then $X$ is a random variable starting from $0$.  It's quite intuitive that $|X(\tau)| = \epsilon$ due to the continuity of $X$.

Comment: @DannyPak-KeungChan Thx for reminding this trivial case.  OP is stuck at "only-if" part.  When he writes $\tau \le t$, I assumed $t < \infty$.  Now I double checked: $t \in \bar{I} \implies t \le T < \infty$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $A=\{t\in [0,T]: |X(t)|\geq  \varepsilon\}.$

If $t\in [0,T]$ and $|X(s)|< \varepsilon$ for all $s\in [0,t]$ then  $A\subset [t,T].$ So if $A$ is not empty then $\tau =\inf A\geq \inf [t,T]=t .$

If $t\in [0,T]$ and $|X(s)| \geq \varepsilon$ for some $s\in [0,t]$ then $s\in A$ so  $\tau =\inf A\leq s\leq t.$

Comment: The second paragraph is insufficient. You've taken $$\lnot (\exists s \in [0,t]: |X(s)| \ge \epsilon),$$ so you have to show $$\lnot (\tau \le t) \iff \tau > t,$$ but you have only shown $\tau \ge t$.

Comment: @GNUSupporter. You are right, I intend to correct this soon