# Find the volume of the region bounded by the coordinate​ planes and a cylinder

Tags: integration, 3d, polar-coordinates, volume, multiple-integral

**The Plane:** $x+y=4$
**The Cylinder:** $y^2+9z^2=16$

I have gone this far but I'm not sure it's true 
$$V=\int\limits_0^4\int\limits_0^{4-x}\int\limits_0^{\sqrt{16-y^2}/9} dz\ dy\ dx$$
PS: Answer can contain $\pi$ if needed.

Comment: The region you are looking for is that bounded by the plane the cylinder and...?

Comment: The volume I need is in the first octant

Comment: Ok I try to elaborate something!

Comment: Please [don't use `\frac` in exponents or limits of integrals](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/5057/290189).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

\begin{align}
V&=\int_0^4\int_0^{4-x}\int_0^{\sqrt{16-y^2}/3} dzdydx \\
&= \int_0^4\int_0^{4-y}\int_0^{\sqrt{16-y^2}/3} dzdxdy \\
&= \int_0^4 (4-y) \, \frac{\sqrt{16-y^2}}3 dy \\
&= \frac13 \left[ 4\int_0^4 \sqrt{16-y^2} dy - \int_0^4 y\sqrt{16-y^2} dy \right] \\
&= \frac13 \left[ 4 \, \frac{\pi(4^2)}{4} + \frac12 \int_0^4 \sqrt{16-y^2} d(16-y^2) \right] \\
&= \frac13 \left[ 4 \, \frac{\pi(4^2)}{4} - \frac12 \,\frac23 \, 16^{3/2} \right] \\
&= \frac13 \left( 16\pi - \frac{64}{3} \right) \\
&= \frac{16(3\pi-4)}{9}
\end{align}

---

Comparison of my answer with another answer

Since pictures are used for illustration, let me also use them.

1. Another answer: fix $x$ first.  This gives rise to a more complicated integrand
   $$V = \frac13\int_0^4 \int_0^{4-x} \sqrt{16-y^2} dydx$$
   As the shaded area of the graph illustrates, one needs to sum the area of a triangle and the sector (involving inverse trigonometric function).  That's why [wolfram-alpha](/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha) complains "standard computation time exceeded...".
   [image: wolfram alpha first way]
2. My answer:  fix $y$ first.  This change of order of integration kills two inner integrals, leaving a much simpler integrand in $y$ only.  This allows [wolfram-alpha](/questions/tagged/wolfram-alpha) to give the exact solution.
   [image: wolfram alpha 2nd way]

Comment: The set up seems to be wrong, it should be $\sqrt{\frac{16-y^2}{9}}$.

Comment: @gimusi Thanks, fixed.  You're right b/c $$y^2+9z^2=16 \iff z^2 = \frac{16-y^2}{9}.$$ You may compare [your approach](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+sqrt(16-y%5E2)%2F3+dy+dx,+x%3D+0+to+4,+y%3D0+to+4-x) (fix $x$ first) with [mine](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=int+sqrt(16-y%5E2)%2F3+dx+dy,+x%3D+0+to+4-y,+y%3D0+to+4) (fix $y$ first).  Both yields an approximate solution $9.64405$ on Wolfram Alpha, but your approach *doesn't* give the exact form in the standard computation time.

Comment: @gimusi Thanks for the answer. I'm glad that I _almost_ set up the integral correctly. Looks like I only forgot how to integrate $\sqrt{16-y^2}$ Can you explain me what exactly you did to integrate that?

Comment: @DenizdaKing I *don't* do a $u$-substitution to integrate this.  Sometimes, thinking of the [geometric meaning](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2778016/290189) of questions can lead to unexpectedly [elementary but elegant solutions](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2776738/290189).

Comment: @DenizdaKing Your set up is uncorrect, indeed you need to fix $\sqrt{\frac{16-y^2}{9}}$ for the integral refer to https://math.stackexchange.com/q/533082/505767

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is (almost) correct, indeed we need to consider that the plane intersect the cylinder according to the following sketch, then the set up is as follow

$$V=\int_0^4 dx\int_0^{4-x}dy\int_0^{\sqrt{\frac{16-y^2}{9}}} dz$$

[image]